# How to insert content type fields directly into Views

Tags: views

I am wanting to place a view into my sidebar like yahoo answers [Yahoo Answers TOP Right Sidebar](https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index?sid=396545144). The block would display the actual fields (to be filled out) from the content type, once submitted it would create the content.

Is there a specific module for this or can it be done directly with views somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: "display the actual fields (to be filled out)" I don't think this is possible with views.

Answer (score 1):

You should use webform module for it. You can display the form to users which the users can fill and submit. You can review the form submissions by going to content/webforms link. 
You can display the webform as a block. You cannot display a content type to be filled in by the user, as only admins can create contents by default. 
You can download webform from this [Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)